# Update failure: failed md5sum validation: sys.vgz

Tags: vmware-esx

LS,

I have ESXi 4, with all the 2009 updates installed. When i try to update the last firmware update, i receive the following error:

Copy of /bootbank/sys.vgz to /tmp/stage/firmware/bank/sys.vgz failed md5sum validation
(8:02:31:29.332 cpu1:1787979)
warning
20-Jan-10 9:42:02 PM

I updated the vmware-tools separatedly, which succeeded.

I receive this message if i use the update GUI, but also when using the CLI tool.

I haven't got a clue how to solve this, anyone any ideas? Or having similar problems?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue on my ESXi 4 machine. Most probable cause is that your / partition is getting full during the update.

The update utility tries to copy files from /bootbank to /tmp/stage, which are both part of the / partition (if you use default ESXi partitioning).

I have not yet tried this, so I can't give a 100% guarantee that it'll work, but I think that creating a soft-link from /tmp/stage to somewhere within the /vmfs partition will do the trick.